# Decrypt Kamstrup WMBUS in Python

Tags: python, cryptography, aes, pycrypto

I have a Kamstrup WMbus water meter sending out frames like this:
`21442D2C529027581B168D2814900939201F0775C6452FBBAC155B46A546035219D51AB8`

I am trying to decrypt this in Python.

Breaking the frame up I have the following values:

- Key  `16ce383ebc0790e928215525cd4f7abf`
- Input IV `2D2C529027581B162890093920000000`
- Input Data   `1F0775C6452FBBAC155B46A546035219D5`

Pasting this into http://www.cryptogrium.com/aes-ctr.html results in a valid decrypted frame:
`bbe57934ddc46a71004400000044000000`

I have tried both PyCrypto and PyCryptodome but neither gives the same correct answer than cryptogrium.com.

```py
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES

# ctr = Crypto.Util.Counter.new(128, initial_value=int("0000002039099028161B582790522C2D", 16))

# cipher = Crypto.Cipher.AES.new(ecryptionKey, Crypto.Cipher.AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)

# secret = Secret()
spec = AES.new(ecryptionKey, AES.MODE_CTR, iv=inputIV)
dataDec = cipher.decrypt(data)
```

The first commented out approach runs but gives the wrong result.
The second one stops with the error:

```
TypeError: Invalid parameters for CTR mode: {'iv': bytearray(b"-,R\x90\'X\x1b\x16(\x90\t9 \x00\x00\x00")}
```

In C# we are using the following which works:

```cs
IBufferedCipher cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
ParametersWithIV ivAndKey = new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(keyBytes), inputIVBytes);
cipher.Init(false, ivAndKey);
...
int length1 = cipher.ProcessBytes(data, 0, data.Length, outBuf, 0);
int length2 = cipher.DoFinal(outBuf, length1);
...
```

I am confused because C# uses the parameters I have: key, data, IV
But Python expects: key, data, counter

Does anyone have an example how I can decrypt this in Python3? Or maybe explain how I should use the IV to set up the counter for AES-CNT?

Comment: Are you certain AES/CTR is the cipher? I thought smart meters were using a modified version of AES/EAX'. Also see [Attacks and Security Proofs of EAX-Prime](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/018.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end one of the examples from https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/87998/Crypto.Cipher.AES.MODE_CTR put me on the right track. After fixing a couple of typos in my code it worked correctly.

```py
def kamstrupDecrypt(meterSerial, frame, payload):
  inputIV = getInputIV(frame)
  print("IV:", binascii.hexlify(inputIV))
  ecryptionKey = getEncryptionKey(meterSerial)
  print("Key:", binascii.hexlify(ecryptionKey))

  counter = Counter.new(128, initial_value = bytes_to_long(inputIV))
  cipher = AES.new(ecryptionKey, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=counter)
  payloadDec = cipher.decrypt(payload)

  print("Decrypted: ", binascii.hexlify(payloadDec))

  return payloadDec
```

Comment: Using pycryptodome (https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/) and including: 
from Crypto.Cipher import AES, 
from Crypto.Util import Counter, 
from Crypto.Util.number import bytes_to_long